# Resizable video does not fully fit to parent div

Tags: javascript, css

I have a video element which is draggable and resizable.
I would like the video element to fit 100% to the parent div
when I resize it, but this is where I fail to do so.

This is what I have so far:

CSS

```
.my-div
{
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    top: 200px;
    left: 400px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #28a745;
}
```

JS

```
let video_div =  document.createElement('div');
video_div.id = 'video-div'
$(video_div).addClass('my-div')
$("body").append(($(video_div).draggable().resizable()))

let video_element;
video_element = document.createElement('video');
$(video_element).attr('id', 'my_video');
$(video_element).attr('class', 'video-js vjs-default-skin');
$(video_element).attr('width', '100%');
$(video_element).attr('height', '100%');
$(video_element).attr('controls', ' ');
$(video_element).attr('preload', 'auto');
$(video_element).attr('data-setup', '{}');

let source = document.createElement('source');
$(source).attr('type', "video/mp4");
$(source).attr('src', "http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4");

$(video_div).append(video_element)

$(video_element).append(source);
```

As you can see  [from this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y04ohxnb/), if you try to resize
the video,it doesn't fit to the parent div
(green background appears behind)

How could I modify my code to achieve that?

**EDIT:** [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pa269cju/) that shows the problen once I add the video-js library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the video tag tries to keep the video aspect ratio.
If you want to fill your parent, you must use the CSS property "object-fit"

In your code, try to add

```
video_element.style.objectFit = "fill";
```

or, using JQuery:

```
$(video_element).css("object-fit", "fill");
```

Of course, doing this will not guarantee a perfect aspect ratio for the video.

More info about the object-fit property here https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Thank you it works, but once I add the video-js library, it is no longer displayed correctly. Could you take a look at the updated fiddle?  Thank you

Comment: @John you're applying width and height with the JQuery "attr" function. Try to use "css" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add % to the height of the surrounding div the one called .my-div (whit this video it is  56.25%). If you change the width the height is always 56.25% of the height and the video should fit.

You can calculate the ratio on this webpage: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/ratios.php